# Reading Pixel values outside Processing frame

Tags: processing

Short question: Is there a way to read RGB values of pixels on the screen, *outside* Processings sketch display window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use's java's Robot class which has a [createScreenCapture()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture(java.awt.Rectangle)) method. This will return an image in java's most common image format: java.awt.BufferedImage.

Luckily Processing's [PImage has a constructor from a java.awt.Image](http://processing.org/reference/javadoc/core/processing/core/PImage.html#PImage(java.awt.Image)) (including subclasses such as BufferedImage), so putting the two together is fairly straight forward:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

PImage shot;

void setup(){
  rectMode(CENTER);
  try
  {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    BufferedImage screenshot =  robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
    shot = new PImage(screenshot);
  }catch (AWTException e){
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to Initialize", e);
  }

}
void draw(){
  image(shot,0,0);
  fill(shot.get(mouseX,mouseY));
  rect(mouseX,mouseY,15,15);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! (also thank you for the x,y,w,h notes on the other question ;))

Comment: Sorry for the much delayed accept and upvote. Works like a charm.